# How can I only make one word 'verbatim'?

Tags: verbatim

How can I make only one word "verbatim" in LaTeX?

For example:

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
The\begin{verbatim} TableForm[]\end{verbatim} shown below is a trig table which....
```

The only thing I want to be "verbatim" is TableForm[]. But when I do 
`begin{verbatim} TableForm[] \end{verbatim}`, the rest of hte words I have become deleted

I want my final output to look like this:

[image]

This is what i have so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb,graphicz,wasysym}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
\item{The \texttt{TableForm[]} shown below is a trig table which shows sine, cosine, and tangent values for integer angles from $0^{\circ}$ through $90^{\circ}$ in steps of $3^{\circ}$. Like we said in class, we could save \verb|TableForm[]|  as a PDF and import it like we've done a few times.}
\bigskip
\end{verbatim}
```

Comment: `The \verb|TableForm[]| shown`... where the same token is used to delimit the start and end of the `\verb` (i.e., `\verb+TableForm[]+` would work equally well).

Comment: that didn't work for me, is there a certain package I need to use in order to use this?

Comment: When I used it, I got the same output as always

Comment: No package required.  But if you provide us with a complete working example, including your documentclass, preamble, and code that *doesn't* work, perhaps more suggestions could be made.

Comment: `\verb|TableForm[]|` would work, but you do not need verbatim, as there are no special characters so you could simply use `\texttt{TableForm[]}`

Comment: i added what i have so far and i tried using `texttt{TableForm[]}` and still just get regular LaTeX font text

Comment: The main use of verbatim means like the dictionary says "exactly the same" all things inside verbatim look same size same blackness same thickness ALSO end verbatim DOES NOT JUST STOP there it stops showing all things on the line not inside the definition

Comment: You are neither using `\verb` nor `\texttt` in your recently added example. Please show the code that is not working for you.

Comment: sorry i just realized i posted the wrong thing. i just updated. @siracusa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works fine when the extra `verbatim` environment and `\item` are removed:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}
The \texttt{TableForm[]} shown below is a trig table which shows sine, cosine,
and tangent values for integer angles from $0^{\circ}$ through $90^{\circ}$ in
steps of $3^{\circ}$. Like we said in class, we could save \verb|TableForm[]|
as a PDF and import it like we've done a few times.
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}` outputs the text `...` literally as given in your code, so all LaTeX commands in it are ignored. You should only use this environment if you want to typeset longer listings of source code or similar.

Comment: thanks so much, I took that part out and used just `texttt{}` and it worked.